# Laravel 4: loading an old library: how?

Tags: laravel, autoload, laravel-4

I have an old library ([phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)) that I'd like to include in my project. I've put it inside vendor, but it doesn't work, as it's not PSR-0 compliant. I don't want it to load for every request, so I didn't put the `require` inside bootstrap autoload.php.

I don't even know, how I can get the root of the app. Running `path()` gives me a URL, not what I'm after.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a libraries directory just like in laravel 3 and include it in your class loader. You can do this via composer or laravel.

```
//composer.json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/libraries",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
    ]
},

//app/starts/global.php
ClassLoader::register(new ClassLoader(array(
    app_path().'/libraries',
)));
```

Autoloading via Laravel does not require you to run "composer dumpautoload" every time a class is created or removed.

UPDATE - L4 Beta 4

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/libraries',
));
```

Comment: I got this after doing what you suggested: Fatal error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit2d7070f81c212e1c659e1f93e987f477' not found in ... vendor/autoload.php on line 7

Comment: That seems like a composer issue. Try running `composer dumpautoload` again and maybe `artisan clear-compiled` for good measure

Comment: @Blessing what if i use namespace in my libraries ? This doesn't work to load the class.