# Where do I put Laravel 4 helper functions that can display flash messages?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've written a simple `display_messages()` function that will search `Session::get('errors')` for flash data and echo it to the screen.

Where do I put this function? In Codeigniter, you had a helpers folder where you could stick all your little global helper methods.

Comment: The HTML::macro() ability of L3 is basically what I'm reinventing the wheel with a helper for... How does L4 attempt to accomplish the same thing. I'd rather not import Meido if I don't have to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Usman suggested,

- create a file **/application/libraries/demo.php**
- define a `class Demo() {` inside it
- call the function like so: `{{ Demo::display() }}`

Works because libraries and models are autoloaded in start.php line 76.  I believe that filenames must match Classnames (note capital).

```
<?php

class Demo {

    public static function display() {

        if( !$message = Session::get('errors'))
            $message = 'No Errors';

        echo "<pre>print_r($message)</pre>";

    }

}
```

Can't quite figure out why I had a problem using the classname Common, there may be a conflict (you could define a namespace if this were important)...

Comment: For Laravel 4, create your lib folder under app/ Also run 'composer dump-autoload' after adding lib path to autoload section of composer.json See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572354/laravel-4-loading-an-old-library-how

Comment: Or you could modify global.php in the ClassLoader::addDirectories() with `app_path().'/libraries'`

Comment: can you give a code example for defining a namespace in this instance and then how you call the "display" method from somewhere

Answer (score 13):

Create a folder `helpers` within your app folder and create a file `application_helper.php`. With such code:

```
// app/helpers/application_helper.php

function display_messages()
{
  exit('Yes');
}
```

Then open your composer.json file in root. autoload `app/helpers/application_helper.php` with composer `files`.

```
"autoload": {
....

    "files": [
        "app/helpers/application_helper.php"
    ]
```

Done, you can now call `display_messages()`.

Some autoloaders may require you to run `composer dump` command for the first time.

Comment: Putting functions out of class statement doesn't work. this method is only for class auto loader.

Comment: `display_messages()` will not work unless the class Common is used first. Helpers should either be apart of a class library to use autoload or via require/include on app start. Otherwise you will have inconsistancies.

Comment: @riotCode Long old Laravel 3 days answer. Updated :)

Comment: Yeah, this is good now. I like using class libraries for helpers better but this way works good as well.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you memeLab provided a very useful answer which helped me a lot. I just wanted to expand on his answer as the "`libraries`" folder was not an auto load directory, at least not in the release/current version of L4 I am using. Also the start.php seems to have been expanded to be  the `start` folder with `global.php`, local.php, and artisan.php.

So to use your own classes for separate libraries or helpers with the L4 lazy auto loader you just have to include whichever folder you want to store these in to the `global.php`. For example I added a `libraries` folder to the directory list.

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    // this a custom path
    app_path().'/libraries',

));
```

Then whatever class you define in that folder as `classname.php` can be called via `CLASSNAME::methodName($someVar);` in your controllers.

```
class CLASSNAME {

    public static function methodName($someVar=NULL) {

        // whatever you want to do...

        return $message;
    }

}
```

So in this fashion you can create a helper class and define different methods to use throughout your controllers. Also be careful defining regular functions outside of your Class in this manner will cause you grief because they will not work (because the class is not always loaded). (for example `someFunctionName($someVar);` instead of `CLASSNAME::methodName($someVar);`) If you want to create functions in this manner you would need to make sure the is loaded, however I will not elaborate on this because it is better practice to use the lazy loader classes for such things so you only load the classes you really need.

Thanks again to memeLab and Usman, I would not have gotten as far without their answers. :)

Answer (score 7):

### For loading **Classes**:

Create `app/libraries/class/Message.php`, and add class in file

```
class Message {
    public static function display() {

    }
}
```

Add `"app/libraries/class"` to `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/libraries/class"
    ]
},
```

Finally run `composer dump-autoload` in command line.

You can access that by `Message::display()`

### For loading plain non-object php **Functions**:

Create `app/libraries/function/display_messages.php`, and add function in file

```
function display_messages() {

}
```

add one line in start/global.php

```
require app_path().'/libraries/function/display_messages.php';
```

You can access that just by `display_messages()`

Answer (score 1):

Add this in app/start/global.php

```
require app_path().'/config/autoload.php';
require app_path().'/start/loader.php';
App::instance('loader',new loader($autoload));
```

create a new file loader.php in app/start and add:

```
class loader{
private $helpers = array();
public $autoload = array(
    'helpers' => array()
);
function __construct($autoload  = array()) {
    if (!empty($autoload))
        $this->autoload = $autoload;
    foreach ($this->autoload as $key => $value)
    {
        $function = strtolower($key);
        $this->$function($value);
    }
}
function helpers($helpers=array())
{
    if (!is_array($helpers))
        $helpers = explode(",",$helpers);
    foreach ($helpers as $key => $value) {
        $this->helper($value);
    }

}
function helper($helper = '',$path = '/')
{
    $folder = app_path().'/helpers'.$path;
    if (file_exists($folder.$helper.'.php') && !in_array($helper, $this->helpers)){
        $this->helpers[] = $helper;
        require $folder.$helper.'.php';
    }
    else{
        $segments = explode('/',$helper);
        if (is_dir($folder.$segments[0])){
            array_shift($segments); 
            $this->helper($segments,$path.$segments[0].'/');
        }
    }
}
```

}

create a new file autoload.php in app/config and add:

```
$autoload['helpers'] = array('functions'); // my autoload helpers!
```

create a new folder helpers in app/ , add your helper files. ( es. myhelper.php )

```
function myhelper()
{
echo 'helper';
}
```

in your controller add:

```
App::make('loader')->helper('myhelper');
    myhelper();
```

Answer (score 0):

In L3, I would normally create a `application/libraries/helpers.php` file, and `require_once()` it in my `application/start.php`.  Similar to how L3 has a `laravel/helpers.php` file.

I'm assuming there is something similar you can do in L4.

EDIT:  Just looking at the source, `app/start/local.php` seems like it might be the place.

Comment: require_once()... with a framework that has an autoloader... that autoloads libraries in application automatically?

Comment: Not really happy with this solution. Haphazardly throwing some random PHP functions only intended to be used as view helpers into app/start/helpers.php and requiring it in app/start/local seems kinda crappy. As intended?

Comment: The original question asked about where to put a function.  Yes, you could make it a class method as memeLab and Usman suggested, but that wasn't what he asked.

Comment: `app/start/local.php` will only be loaded in the local environment.

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial and i think is the easiest method: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/50/creating-a-helpers-file

1. First create the file app/helpers.php
2. Then either load it at the bottom of **app\start\global.php** as follows.

   // at the bottom of the file 
    require app_path().'/helpers.php';

Or change your **composer.json** file and dump the autoloader.

```
 {
        "autoload": {
            "files": [
                "app/helpers.php"
            ]
        }
    }
```

**$ composer dump-auto**

3. then you can write your functions in helpers.php and call them from anywhere

   ```
   function myfunction($result){ 
        return $result;
       }
   ```

Answer (score -17):

open `root_folder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`

and you can add your function

```
if ( ! function_exists('display_messages'))
{
    function display_messages()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't attempt to hack the internals of the framework. These changes will be overwritten by Composer updates.