# How to use external php classes in laravel framework?

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, laravel-4

I'm switching from Codeigniter to Laravel. In CI its easy to user external libraries or classes, just put it in `application/libraries` folder then load it from your controller by:

```
$this->load->library('libraryName')
```

Now, I wanna do the same thing in Laravel. I used this scenario :

1. Create a folder inside my `app` folder called `libraries`.
2. Change the `composer.json` (which located in the root) as the following:

   ```
   "autoload": {
     "classmap": [
       "app/commands",
       "app/controllers",
       "app/models",
       "app/database/migrations",
       "app/database/seeds",
       "app/tests/TestCase.php",
       "app/libraries" // this was added
     ]
   },
   ```
3. And from CMD run the command `composer dump-autoload`.

My class look like this:

```
class Messages{
    function errorMessage(){//....}
    function successMessage(){//....}
}
```

Class stored in file called `Messages.php` which located in `app\libraries` folder.

I still have the same error:

> Class 'Messages' not found

What is the problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Where are you creating you Messages class?  What's its name and what's its file?  Also, where/when are you instantiating it from?

Comment: as i said in the question, class called `messages` and stored in file called `messages.php` and located in `app\libraries`. and i need to instantiate it from contoller or rout.php file.

Comment: Is that app/libraries/messages or app/libraries/Messages.php?

Comment: app/libraries/Messages.php and class name is Messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new folder: app/your-folder-name and put your class in that folder
2. Open the globals.php file in app/start
3. You should see this:

   ```
   ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

     app_path().'/commands',
     app_path().'/controllers',
     app_path().'/models',
     app_path().'/database/seeds',

   ));
   ```
4. Add your folder with your class to this array

   ```
   app_path().'/your-folder-name'
   ```

More info can be found here: [Where do I put Laravel 4 helper functions that can display flash messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902589/where-do-i-put-laravel-4-helper-functions-that-can-display-flash-messages/17194148#17194148)

Comment: You can avoid editing the `ClassLoader` in globals.php by simply running `composer dump-autoload` *after* you've created the Messages.php file in `app/libraries`. If you add a new class to the folder, of if you rename a class, just run `composer dump-autoload` afterwards to pick up the change. Or, for bonus points, you can use PSR-4 autoloading and a namespace, which is more in line with how this will be handled in Laravel 5; an excellent tutorial for that is [here](https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading).

Answer (score 0):

check your file with autoloading classes /vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
your class should in there.
if it is - check do you actually using composer autoloading on your request?